# How to fix this qiuck Cisco AnyConnect window when Win10 starts?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

When I boot my Windows 10, the Cisco AnyConnect quickly flashes out a window. I managed to capture it. I never see it before. Though it looks like an error, I can still use the AnyConnect to connect the VPN successfully.

Why it shows up and anyway to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it just starts during boot. You can use autoruns from Microsoft sysinternals https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx if you do not want the program to start on boot. This program will show *everything* that starts on boot.

Comment: Just remembered the other tool, msconfig! Press ctrl+R to bring up a run prompt and enter msconfig. It's another tool that is a bit simpler to use for stopping programs that auto start. This will only show a subset. Hope it helps!

Comment: I use the Task Manger to disable the auto start of Cisco AnyConnect.

Comment: Correct, that is a newer way in W10, maybe 8?

Comment: Its win10 I am using.

Comment: I was just saying I think the feature is in W8 as well :)